# 64GB SD card missing files but correct size

Tags: sd-card, file-recovery

I have a 64GB Samsung Evo class 10, which suddenly stopped working on my phone; can't mount/detect it.

I accessed the card via laptop, which says 28GB used.  But when I copied or scanned the files, its just 12GB

Folders:

```
Camera     - 16GB++ - says empty folder
Camera (0) - 12GB ++ - copied from old phone
```

I tried scanning with Malwarebytes,NOD32 and Avg but no malware found.

- I tried check disk using right click, but after 6hrs, it hadn't finished, so I cancelled.
- Show hidden files is already checked.
- I tried check disk command suggested by users on the first page but it takes too long.

Timeline:
- after 1hr++ - Windows is verifying files and folders

- after 30mins ++ - Corruption was found while examining files in directory \DCIM\Camera\ (0)
- after 30mins ++ - Corruption was found while examining files in directory \DCIM\Camera\ (1)
- after 1hr ++ - Corruption was found while examining files in directory \DCIM\Camera\ (2)
- after 38mins ++ - Corruption was found while examining files in directory \DCIM\Camera\ (8)
- after 30mins ++ - Corruption was found while examining files in directory \DCIM\Camera\ (10)
- after 26mins ++ - Corruption was found while examining files in directory \DCIM\Camera\ (15)
- after 5hrs from start "The wrong volume is in the drive. Please insert volume into drive G:"
- re inserted sd card, now its doing the updates fast Corruption was found while examining files in directory \DCIM\Camera\ (XXX)
- after 6hrs++ -

  \Camera.OutFocus.
  Entries 0 to 4095 were affected.
  The bad sectors will only be repaired if the "/r" opt
  Corruption due to bad sectors was found while examini
  oid.
  Entries 0 to 4095 were affected.
  Corruption due to bad sectors was found while examini
  roid_secure.
  Entries 0 to 4095 were affected.
  Corruption was found while examining files and direct
  An error occurred while examining the volume bitmap.

This is the folder with 16GB on it and was used by the Camera. I am leaving this on for the day. i thought it was going do update me like (1) (2) (3), it skipped to (8).

Any info why this happened? Any way to fix this?

Comment: Seems like it is broken.  This might just be the filesystem, in which case a format might fix it.  Otherwise it is physically broken and you'll want a replacement.  For me, when sd cards start playing up, it is time to replace, as I wouldn't want to risk losing images.

Comment: I want to replace, but i just want to retrieve the 16gb worth of Baby pics. then im buying a new one.

Comment: Have you let the chkdsk complete?

Comment: its 4hrs now and continuing. im updating the Timeline. i estimated around 2000 images and around 10 small videos on that folder.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the table or file system is corrupt, but the files themselves are OK. This could be caused by hardware failure, or some other cause of corruption - external source of magnetism, a glitch from the camera, etc. I'd hesitate to make any repairs to the disk before you recover files, as it could permanently corrupt or lose more data. After recovery you may be able to re-partition the card and continue to use it, at the risk of another failure.

I would try using a file recovery program like photorec/testdisk, recuva, or similar. The more important the files, the more care you will want to take in safeguarding against additional loss. If possible, make a block level copy of the drive and run recovery on the copy.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

https://www.piriform.com/recuva

Comment: And take it as a MASSIVE lesson in the importance of backups. There is no excuse any more for people to not backup their most important data...